# Geometric Intuition behind Flatness

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm looking for a nice geometric interpretation for ***flat*** morphisms between schemes. In wiki's article

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism_of_schemes#Intuition

is stated that flat families correspond to families of varieties which vary "continuously".

Futhermore as an example is given by

$${\displaystyle \operatorname {Spec} \left({\frac {\mathbb {C} [x,y,t]}{(xy-t))}}\right)\to \operatorname {Spec} (\mathbb {C} [t])}$$

What I don't understand here what is concretely meant by "continuously"?

The continuity of parametrisation $V_t = xy -t$?

Does anybody know another nice geometric interpretation for flatness? Is every morphism flat which provides such "varying family" of subvarieties by some parameters?

Comment: This is actually infamous for being one of those properties that is used because it turns out to work. I seem to recall there being at least one MO post about this

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75317/flatness-in-complex-analytic-geometry/75358#75358 is a semi-famous MO question which may be helpful. The story is that truly understanding flatness is hard! The basic statement that flat implies fibers have the same hilbert polynomial (and same dimension) is probably the thing that's most helpful to me, but I'm not claiming it's a royal road and there's certainly a fair amount of subtlety left.

Comment: Two more related MO posts: [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6789/why-are-flat-morphisms-flat), [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35127/why-does-the-algebraic-condition-of-flatness-on-the-structure-sheaves-give-a-go).